# Make UIView work like a UIButton

Tags: iphone, user-interface, uiview, uibutton

I built a `Custom Cell` in IB and in it created a view that represents a button. It has `Labels` and `ImageViews` in it.

I want to know if there is a way to make that view act like a button. That is, show a shadow and call a method when is pressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best is to make it a button. You can use `UIButtonTypeCustom` and set the background to the cell you've created.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Just implement `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` and you can do everything you could do in a button action `@selector`.

As for the shadow and the rounded rectangle button feel, if you use a single cell in a section with `UITableViewStyleGrouped`, it will be pretty close.

Answer (score 0):

You can use UITapGestureRecognizer and pass the event through a delegate or use UIControl which is a subclass of UIView but with UIButton tap events like touchUpInside and so, and then pass the event with a delegate to your view